# Trying to update a dictionary with another "dictionary" from optparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have defined a dictionary in my code called `cfg`.

```
cfg = { 'debug': 1, 'verbose': 1, 'cfgfile': 'my.cfg' }
```

Using `ConfigParser` I parse a config file that can be used to override hard-coded values defined in `cfg` above and merge them as follows:

```
config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read(cfg['cfgfile'])
cfg.update(dict(config.items('Main')))
```

The above all works correctly.

I now call a function that uses `optparse` to parse command line arguments.

```
def parseOptions():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-d", "", dest="debug",        action="store_true",             default=False, help="enable additional debugging output")
    parser.add_option("-v", "", dest="verbose",      action="store_true",             default=False, help="enable verbose console output")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    return options
```

Back in `main()`, `options` appears to be a dictionary upon visual inspection:

```
options = parseOptions()
print options

{'debug': False, 'verbose': False}
```

When I try and update my `cfg` dict, I get this error:

```
cfg.update(dict(options))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 176, in <module>
    cfg.update(dict(options))
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

The type of options is an instance of Values:

```
print "type(options)=%s instanceof=%s\n" % (type(options), options.__class__.__name__)

type(options)=<type 'instance'> instanceof=Values
```

How can I update my `cfg` dictionary with the values in `options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `vars()`:

```
options = parseOptions()
option_dict = vars(options)
cfg.update(option_dict)
```